# using union all produce the following result as mentioned below

Tags: mysql

Write a query to display person_name,contact_number,entry_time and exit_time for which balance is greater than 30 and amount is greater than 35.
Display all the records sorted in ascending order based on entry_time.

The travel_card table consists of id,person_name,contact_number,balance
and the travel_payment table consists of id,travel_card_id,entry_station_id,exit_station_id,entry_time,exit_time

```
SELECT tc.person_name,tc.contact_number,tp.entry_time,tp.exit_time 
    FROM travel_card tc INNER JOIN travel_payment tp 
      ON tc.id=tp.travel_card_id 
   WHERE balance>30
UNION ALL
SELECT tc.person_name,tc.contact_number,tp.entry_time,tp.exit_time 
    FROM travel_card tc LEFT JOIN travel_payment tp 
      ON tc.id=tp.travel_card_id 
   WHERE amount>35 
ORDER BY entry_time ASC;
```

I done with above code but it producing rows with repitition and i also tried using distinct infront of person_name but the result still producing duplicate rows

Comment: Please post your database schema, sample data, and expected outcome.

Comment: What if you ditch the `UNION ALL` and simply edit you `WHERE balance>30 and amount>35`?